# Push-down automaton for a language with number of 1s double than 0s

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

This questions is taken from a complexity theory course.

> Design a push-down automaton that recognize $L = x \in \{0,1\}^* $
>   such that $x$ contains a number of ones double than a number of zeros.

Example: x = 011011, 100011111, 011011110.

**My approach**

I tried to push on the stack a symbol "A" every time I read "0", than pop "A" from the stack when I read two consecutive "1" but this approach works not for every string $x$ in the language. Maybe the final PDA is non-deterministic. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this algorithm:

- Initialize a variable $x := 0$.
- Scan the string, left to right. If you see $1$, set $x := x + 1$, if you see $0$, set $x := x - 2$.
- When you are done, accept iff $x = 0$.

It should be obvious that it recognizes your language. Can you figure out a way to implement it replacing the counter with the stack?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm for what I think could be a solution:

```
program_recL(entry) is
    stack: type_stack
    while read(entry) != $ do
        if read(entry) == 0 then
            if empty(stack) then
                push(stack, 0)
                push(stack, 0)
            else
                if top(stack) == 0 then
                    push(stack, 0)
                    push(stack, 0)
                else
                    pop(stack)
                    push(stack, 0)
                endif
            endif
        else
            if empty(stack) then
                push(stack, 1)
            else
                if top(stack) == 1 then
                    push(stack, 1)
                else
                    pop(stack)
                endif
            endif
        endif

        next(entry)
    endwhile

    if is_empty(stack) then
        accept()
    endif
end
```

The basic idea here is that every 0 has x2 value for each 1, meaning we need to push two 0s every time we read a 0 on our entry. This will translate into needing two 1s to get a 0 popped from the stack, in other words, a number of 1s double than a number of 0s.

Answer (score -2):

You need a 2-stack PDA to solve this problem.

Since the language you've given is non-context free, it's more powerful than a single stack PDA. More specifically, your language the union of many CFLs and non-CFLs.
The inputs that seem to be working with your way can be recognized by a single stack PDA. e.g.: S -> 0A11    A -> S    which is the language {0^n1^2n, n>=0}
                 S -> 11A0    A -> S    which is the language {1^2n1^n, n>=0}
                               .
                               .
                               .
However, there is no way to describe others with a context-free grammar.

Comment: No, you don't need a "2-stack PDA" (friends call him a Turing Machine, by the way). Consider this grammar: $S \rightarrow \varepsilon$, $S \rightarrow S0S1S1S$ and cyclic variants. One arrow is obvious, the other is structural induction.